# OpenAM 10, Fedlet App, how to check if user is already logged in

Tags: openam

I have a Fedlet J2EE application working with OpenAM 10.
I would like to know how I can check if the user is already logged into the OpenAM server.
The goal is to make this check to get the identity attributes without showing again the OpenAM login screen.
Anybody knows how can I check if the user is already logged in a J2EE Fedlet application?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The SAML specification allows doing this, the isPassive flag in a SAML AuthnRequest would achieve exactly what you want.